# Solr 7.6.0: How to combine different QueryParser in one query?

Tags: solr, edismax

I just want to combine block join query and main-query with edismax-parser as I do it for solr < 7.2

```
berlin OR _query_:"{!parent which=type:book}page_content:berlin"
```

But edismax cannot be the default-Parser for this purpose any more(s. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11501)

So it works with lucene-QueryParser for querying parents:

```
q={!parent which="type:book"}{!edismax qf='page_content' v='berlin'}
```

it still works for adding main query like

```
q=title:berlin* AND {!parent which="type:book"}{!edismax qf='page_content' v='berlin'}
```

but when I try

```
q={!edismax qf='title' v='berlin'} OR {!parent which="type:book"}{!edismax qf='page_content' v='berlin'}
```

only the first part of the query is evaluated.

My docs are:

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">1</field>
    <field name="type">book</field>
    <field name="title">Book about Berlin</field>
    <field name="pages">
    <doc>
      <field name="id">11</field>
      <field name="type">page</field>
      <field name="page_content">berlin in winter</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
      <field name="id">12</field>
      <field name="type">page</field>
      <field name="page_content">berlin in spring</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
      <field name="id">13</field>
      <field name="type">page</field>
      <field name="page_content">berlin in summer</field>
    </doc>
  </field>
 </doc>
 <doc>
    <field name="id">2</field>
    <field name="type">book</field>
    <field name="title">Big book about Tokio</field>
    <field name="pages">
    <doc>
      <field name="id">21</field>
      <field name="type">page</field>
      <field name="page_content">tokio in winter</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
      <field name="id">22</field>
      <field name="type">page</field>
      <field name="page_content">tokio in spring</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
      <field name="id">23</field>
      <field name="type">page</field>
      <field name="page_content">tokio in summer</field>
    </doc>
  </field>
 </doc>
</add>
```

Does anybody have the same problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I finally rewrote entirely my answer, my assumption wasn't right ! Hopefully `uf` comes to the rescue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because, as of Solr 7.3, the defaults regarding searchable fields for edismax actually *prohibits* the use of embedded query.

Fortunately, this behavior can be managed with [`uf`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html#TheExtendedDisMaxQueryParser-TheufParameter) parameter.

> **uf** : Specifies which schema fields the end user is allowed to explicitly query and to toggle whether embedded Solr queries are
> supported. This parameter supports wildcards. Multiple fields must be
> separated by a space.
>
> The default is to allow all fields and no embedded Solr queries,
> equivalent to `uf=* -_query_`.

Set `uf=* _query_` to allow embedded queries.

I tested it on Solr 7.7.1, it works but I had to **wrap the embedded query in double quotes otherwise the *whole* query fails** returning 0 result without any notice.

This query should work :

```
defType=edismax&uf=* _query_&q=title:berlin* OR "{!parent which="type:book"}page_content:berlin"
```

Note : There are examples in documentation for Solr < 7.3 mentioning a comma-separated list in `uf` parameter, but the expected separator is definitely a space.

For those who are not using *edismax* you will have to set `luceneMatchVersion=7.1.0` for full backward compatibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric, but as far as I understood and tested it is not allowed for solr > 7.1 to use any other parser when edismax is a default one ( SOLR-11501). Up to 7.2 it works

Comment: I cannot try it now, but definitely it doesn’t work if I define edismax as default parser in solrconfig what schould be the same as to put it in url-param

Comment: @katja ... damn ! Meanwhile I realized that the schema fields for edismax actually *prohibits* the use of *_query_* so you have to explicitly set `uf=*,_query_` for this to work (it should work inline as well). Also you can still set `luceneMatchVersion=7.1.0` for full backward compatibility..  I've no time to dig it right now but I will make some test in the weekend and update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Eric, it works defType=edismax&uf=* _query_&q=book AND _query_:"{!parent which=type:book}page_content:berlin"

Comment: Cool ! Please consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), thank you for your feedbacks